# how to convert Gif to spritesheet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, gif, sprite-sheet

i am getting frames from gif using Libgif.
and then i am appending those frames in the div with Id = frames.
then i am taking those frames and trying to add each frames one after the other in canvas to make a spritesheet.

in the end i am getting an image in canvas but instead of getting different frames i am getting same image in the spritesheet.
Please help me find the issue.

I had taken canvas width 10000 assuming a gif wont have frames more than 100.

```js
c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
ctx.beginPath();
var imageGiF = "";
var total = 0;
let canvasWidth = 0;
let canvasHeight = 0;
$('div.gifimage img').each(function(idx, img_tag) {
  var total = 0;
  if (/^.+\.gif$/.test($(img_tag).prop("src"))) {
    var rub = new SuperGif({
      gif: img_tag,
      progressbar_height: 0
    });
    rub.load(function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < rub.get_length(); i++) {
        total += 1;
        rub.move_to(i);
        // var canvas = cloneCanvas(rub.get_canvas());
        var canvas = rub.get_canvas().toDataURL("image/png");
        img = $('<img id = "gifframe' + i + '"src= "' + canvas + '" class= frameimages>');

        $("#frames").append(img);

      }
      var frameimages = document.getElementById("frames").querySelectorAll(".frameimages");
      var totalimages = frameimages.length;

      x = 0;
      y = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < frameimages.length; i++) {
        img = document.getElementById("gifframe" + i + "");
        img.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(img, i * 100, 0, 100, 100);
          total++;
          console.log(total);
        }
      }
      totalwidth = (total) * 100;
      c.width = totalwidth;
      c.height = 100;
      setTimeout(() => {
        imageGiF = c.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log(imageGiF);
        // addBgimg(imageGiF)
      }, 10);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js/master/libgif.js"></script>
<div class="gifimage" id="placehere">
  <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/bzUwzbxcvJ3XQlcnoi/giphy.gif" alt="">

</div>
<div id="frames" class="classGIF"></div>
<canvas id='myCanvas' width="10000" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: I made you the snippet you should have made yourself

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I see the animation and I see the individual frames.

Comment: @Tschallacka images which are added in the canvas is same . it should be different as it is a spritesheet. thats the last frame of the gif. i dont know why it is happening.there is an image Source or dataUrl which we get from canvas. check that image closely you will get whats the problem

Comment: Ah, now I see, the images at the bottom were hidden by the console input.

Comment: @Tschallacka yes i am sure this is some minor mistake which i am doing . may be i am using wrong logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looping through the images, using `img` in your event handler.
However, this variable `img` in the outer scope was overridden by every loop, until it was finished looping through everything, then `img` was stuck on the last frame added.
Then when the event handler triggered, it added the last frame in every instance, because that was the value of `img` at that point. The loop was done before the images could load.

By adding it to it's own [scope](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript#:%7E:text=Scope%20in%20JavaScript%20refers%20to,declared%20inside%20of%20a%20block) by wrapping it in a function, the variable is preserved.

I also modified your code to store the DOM img elements in an array, so you don't need expensive DOM lookups which makes your code a tad bit faster.

I added comments in the code to explain my changes.

```js
c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
ctx.beginPath();
var imageGiF = "";
var total = 0;
let canvasWidth = 0;
let canvasHeight = 0;
$('div.gifimage img').each(function(idx, img_tag) {
  var total = 0;
  if (/^.+\.gif$/.test($(img_tag).prop("src"))) {
    var rub = new SuperGif({
      gif: img_tag,
      progressbar_height: 0
    });
    rub.load(function() {
      // An array for the image references
      let images = [];
      // Keep the reference to save on expensive DOM lookups every iteration.
      let frames = $("#frames");
      for (let i = 0; i < rub.get_length(); i++) {
        total += 1;
        rub.move_to(i);
        // var canvas = cloneCanvas(rub.get_canvas());
        var canvas = rub.get_canvas().toDataURL("image/png");
        img = $('<img id = "gifframe' + i + '"src= "' + canvas + '" class="frameimages">');
        
        // Use the reference to append the image.
        frames.append(img);
        
        // Add image to images array with the current index as the array index.
        // Use the jQuery get method to get the actual DOM element.
        images[i] = img.get(0);
      }
      var frameimages = document.getElementById("frames").querySelectorAll(".frameimages");
      var totalimages = frameimages.length;

      x = 0;
      y = 0;
      
      // Loop through all the images in the image array
      // Using a scope so the reference to img won't be overridden.
      images.forEach((img, index) => {
        img.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(img, index * 100, 0, 100, 100);
          total++;
          console.log(total);
        } 
      })
      
      
      totalwidth = (total) * 100;
      c.width = totalwidth;
      c.height = 100;
      setTimeout(() => {
        imageGiF = c.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log(imageGiF);
        // addBgimg(imageGiF)
      }, 10);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#frames { display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js/master/libgif.js"></script>
<div class="gifimage" id="placehere">
  <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/bzUwzbxcvJ3XQlcnoi/giphy.gif" alt="">

</div>
<div id="frames" class="classGIF"></div>
<canvas id='myCanvas' width="10000" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Finally it's working